# building custom kernel on redhat 9

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kernel, compile, initrd

I'm trying to build a `kernel 2.4` on `redhat 9`. but when I go through theses steps:

- make menuconfig
- make dep
- make bzImage
- make install

  they return no error but when I try to boot into it, it returns "kernel panic:no init found"!

Comment: how about **make modules** and **make modules_install**?  Additional note: kernel 2.4 is incredible old as 3.13.1 is current you may wish to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Run `make mrproper` first of all, before `make menuconfig`.

This will make `make modules` and `make modules_install` work without errors.

Then run `make install` after all the other steps.